# For CUDA, is there a guarantee that Ternary Operator can avoid branch divergence?

Tags: cuda

I have read a lot of threads about CUDA branch divergence, telling me that using ternary operator is better than if/else statements, because ternary operator doesn't result in branch divergence.
I wonder, for the following code:

```
foo = (a > b) ? (bar(a)) : (b);
```

Where bar is another function or some more complicate statements, is it still true that there is no branch divergence ?

Comment: I don't think there are any guarantees that a ternary operator in source code would never result in a branch. In general if-then-else sequences and ternary operators are treated quite similar by the compiler: in either case it will try to emit code that minimizes branching by use of predicated instructions or select-type instructions (the hardware equivalent of a ternary operator). In particular for tight local branching, you wouldn't want to worry about branch-free code (at least not until a profiler tells you there is a problem) as the compiler will typically take care of these things.

Comment: There is no guarantee.

Comment: `using ternary operator is better than if/else statements`. This is false. The  optimizer is pretty good nowadays for both cases. I usually trust the compiler to do the right thing, but when in doubt the only way to be sure is to check the generated assembly.

Comment: OK, it seems assembly code is the only choice, although I hate it ...

Comment: @njuffa your comment is pretty comprehensive.  If you wanted to provide an answer I would upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what sources you consulted, but with the CUDA toolchain there is no noticeable performance difference between the use of the ternary operator and the equivalent `if-then-else` sequence in most cases. In the case where such differences are noticed, they are due to second order effects in the code generation, and the code based on `if-then-else` sequence may well be faster in my experience. In essence, ternary operators and tightly localized branching are treated in much the same way. There can be no guarantees that a ternary operator may not be translated into machine code containing a branch.

The GPU hardware offers multiple mechanisms that help avoiding branches and the CUDA compiler makes good use of these mechanisms to minimize branches. One is predication, which can be applied to pretty much any instruction. The other is support for select-type instructions which are essentially the hardware equivalent of the ternary operator. The compiler uses if-conversion to translate short branches into branch-less code sequences. Often, it choses a combination of predicated code and a uniform branch. In cases of non-divergent control flow (all threads in a warp take the same branch) the uniform branch skips over the predicated code section.

Except in cases of extreme performance optimization, CUDA can (and should) be written in natural idioms that are clear and appropriate to the task at hand, using either `if-then-else` sequences or ternary operators as you see fit. The compiler will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 7):

(I would like to add the comment for @njuffa's answer but my reputation is not enough)
I found the performance different between them with my program.
The if-clause style costs 4.78ms:

```
// fin is {0-4}, range_limit = 5
if(fin >= range_limit){
   res_set = res_set^1;
   fx_ref = fx + (fxw*(float)DEPTH_M_H/(float)DEPTH_BLOCK_X);
   fin = 0;
} 
// then branch for next loop iteration.

// nvvp report these assemblies.
    @!P1 LOP32I.XOR R48, R48, 0x1;
    @!P1 FMUL.FTZ R39, R7, 14;
    @!P1 MOV R0, RZ;
    MOV R40, R48;
    {    @!P1 FFMA.FTZ R6, R39, c[0x2][0x0], R5;
    @!P0 BRA `(.L_35);        }    // the predicate also use for loop's branching
```

And the ternary style costs 4.46ms:

```
res_set = (fin < range_limit) ? res_set: (res_set ^1);
fx_ref  = (fin < range_limit) ? fx_ref : fx + (fxw*(float)DEPTH_M_H/(float)DEPTH_BLOCK_X) ;
fin     = (fin < range_limit) ? fin:0;
//comments are where nvvp mark the instructions are for the particular code line
    ISETP.GE.AND P2, PT, R34.reuse, c[0x0][0x160], PT;   //res_set
    FADD.FTZ R27, -R25, R4;
    ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R34, c[0x0][0x160], PT;         //fx_ref
    IADD32I R10, R10, 0x1;
    SHL R0, R9, 0x2;
    SEL R4, R4, R27, P1;
    ISETP.LT.AND P1, PT, R10, 0x5, PT;
    IADD R33, R0, R26;
    {         SEL R0, RZ, 0x1, !P2;
    STS [R33], R58;        }
    {         FADD.FTZ R3, R3, 74.75;
    STS [R33+0x8], R29;        }
    {    @!P0 FMUL.FTZ R28, R4, 14;                     //fx_ref
    STS [R33+0x10], R30;        }
    {         IADD32I R24, R24, 0x1;
    STS [R33+0x18], R31;        }
    {         LOP.XOR R9, R0, R9;                      //res_set
    STS [R33+0x20], R32;        }
    {         SEL R0, R34, RZ, P0;                     //fin
    STS [R33+0x28], R36;        }
    {    @!P0 FFMA.FTZ R2, R28, c[0x2][0x0], R3;       //fx_ref
```

The inserted lines are from the next loop iteration calculation.
I think in the case of many instructions shared the same predicate value, the ternary style may provide more opportunity for ILP optimization.

Comment: These observations don't say anything without an estimate of the variation within replicates of runs of the same code. If the standard error in each was 0.2 ms, then these results are statistically identical.

Comment: @mabraham I measured the elapsed time by using cudaEvent that should be the less overhead method AFAIK. 
Before the kernel's measurement, I called the short dummy kernel to mask the API reference delay of CUDA, then begin the cudaEvent, loop the kernel call for thousands of times (few seconds) without memory transaction, re-trigger the cudaEvent, then average the elapsed time.